# Adding a public constructor to a JPA field-annotated POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm super confused about field access JPA-annotated POJOs.

How are you supposed to set (or get) the fields when they are private? I prefer to use field annotations (I'm not using the getter/setter approach), but I'm a bit confused about how it is going to work.

Can I add a public constructor to my POJO, so I can easily set the fields? Should I add getter methods for the fields I know I will need to access? Should I just make all of the fields public?

Right now, I guess I forsee my POJO looking like this: Field access, public constructor, and @Transient annotations over functions which modify raw DB data - such as wrapping dates into Date objects (converting from the stored MS value) and the likes.

I am getting near my first tests with my POJOs and DAO. I've never ran hibernate code before, just been learning about it for weeks. I'm excited, and the answers to this question ought to get me just over the hump.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an example class which demonstrates what you are attempting to do.  You are able to have a public 'default' constructor if you wish,  but i am currently more concerned about what you are attempting to do with @Transient annoatation and 'raw DB data'

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0PCCvQ5X - basically the entire source of what I currently have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a beginner at hibernate as well.. based on what I have read, you cannot escape having getters or setters and public constructor is okay to have. I use a public constructor to populate the bean.

Comment: Thanks man! I gather some of my questions are the result of not "diving in", but thanks for the reassurance.